# How to I turn n*n*n*n as n^k where k is the number of times n is multiplied?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to express the number 60 as the product of its prime numbers.
For example, I have a list a = [5 , 3 , 2 , 2]
I was able to express this list as: 60 = 5 * 3 * 2 * 2 but I would like to express it as 60 = 5 * 3 * 2 ^ 2
another example would be 540 = 5 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 2 as : 540 =  5 * 3 ^ 3 * 2 ^ 2.
Ive tried this:

```
 for i in prime_factors:
    if prime_factors.count(i) > 1 :
        a=prime_factors.count(i)
        prime_factors.index(i) == ' * '.join(i^a)
```

i dont understand why it doesnt work.
I have no idea how to code this or even where to start .
please help

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: create a dictionary of integers.  The key of the dictionary is a number from your list of factors, and then value for that key is the number of times you've seen that in your list.  So just run through your list, upping the count in the dictionary for the key that matches that number.  defaultdict would be a big help here

Comment: @CryptoFool: `collections.Counter` is specifically designed for this scenario; `defaultdict(int)` works, but `Counter` has additional optimizations and features specifically for counting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. It looks like you've got the right idea, but the last line of your code is way off-base, plus, even if you fix it, you're going to have duplicates. Just to start, `^` is actually the XOR operator, and you're using `str.join()` too early. I'm not sure why the question's been closed, but do read [ask], which has tips like starting with your own research.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - yeah, your answer is better man.  I like to leave something of what's going on out in the open so that beginning programmers can start to pick up how to do more complex things that don't fit the mold of an existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of each factor, then format the result as `x ^ y` whenever the count is greater than 1:

```py
from collections import Counter

prime_numbers = [2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3]
counts = Counter(prime_numbers)

result = [f'{k}' + (f' ^ {v}' if v > 1 else '') for k, v in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x:-x[0])]

print(' * '.join(result))
```

Output:

```
5 * 3 ^ 3 * 2 ^ 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [5 , 3 , 2 , 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]

tallies = defaultdict(int)

for num in a:
    tallies[num] += 1

r = ""
for k, v in sorted(tallies.items()):
    if r:
        r += ' * '
    r += f"{k}^{v}" if v > 1 else f"{k}"

print(r)
```

Result:

```
2^4 * 3^3 * 5
```